# Highlight the edges of part of picture in Python from 4 tuples with 2 values in each

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, highlight

I am trying to highlight the barcode given in the picture. I am using DBR to decode the barcodes and DBR spits out the localization point in a list with 4 tuples inside and 2 values inside each tuple as shown below.

```
Localization Points: [(108, 136), (200, 136), (204, 154), (107, 154)]
```

This is how the picture looks like currently.

[image]

I want to be able to highlight the barcode based on the localization points given by DBR library. I found a very useful stackoverflow solution but it requires only 4 values instead of a tuple. If I manually put these values taken from the tuple then it will work like this.

[image]

Obviously I don't want to hardcode it. I used this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758263/how-to-highlight-part-of-image-with-python-imaging-library-pil) from stackoverflow which works good but I am not able to make it working with the given tuple.

Any idea how to get this to working.

Here is a function I took from the mentioned solution.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageColor, ImageDraw, ImageEnhance

def highlight_area(img, region, factor, outline_color=None, outline_width=1):
    """ Highlight specified rectangular region of image by `factor` with an
        optional colored  boarder drawn around its edges and return the result.
    """
    img = img.copy()  # Avoid changing original image.
    img_crop = img.crop(region)

    brightner = ImageEnhance.Brightness(img_crop)
    img_crop = brightner.enhance(factor)

    img.paste(img_crop, region)

    # Optionally draw a colored outline around the edge of the rectangular region.
    if outline_color:
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)  # Create a drawing context.
        left, upper, right, lower = region  # Get bounds.
        coords = [(left, upper), (right, upper), (right, lower), (left, lower),
                  (left, upper)
                  ]
        draw.line(coords, fill=outline_color, width=outline_width)

    return img


img = Image.open('C:/Users/username/test/product1.jpg')

red = ImageColor.getrgb('red')
cpu_socket_region = 108,136,204,154 ## [(108, 136), (200, 136), (204, 154), (107, 154)] ## This tuple should be replaced instead of hardcoded values i.e. 108, 136, 204, 154
img2 = highlight_area(img, cpu_socket_region, 2.5, outline_color=red, outline_width=2)

#img2.save('motherboard_with_cpu_socket_highlighted.jpg')
img2.show()
```

Comment: the code basically already does what you want, just pass in `coords` instead of creating it from `region`

Comment: it says "type tuple doesn't define __round__ method" when I directly pass the tuple. I am thinking to loop through a tuple and only pack the coordinates that way. I understand that's not efficient but can't think of any other way.

Comment: Not sure what you were doing to get that error!  that said, I noticed that `ImageEnhance.Brightness` can't be used with an arbitrary polygon so I've composed a real answer...

Comment: I removed the opencv tag because the question isn't about opencv but about geometry/drawing, which you do with PIL anyway. -- you used to have four points describing a parallelogram (polygon). you could have drawn that, right? you found some code on the internet? and now you want other people on the internet to change it to suit your purpose? what code did you write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PIL's [`ImageEnhance`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageEnhance.html) module only allows you to apply the operation to the whole image (i.e. a rectangle) and not an arbitrary polygon.  Therefore to get the enhancement clipped to this, you need to mask off the relevant part of the image.

The following does that, as well as swapping from [`ImageDraw.line`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.line) to [`ImageDraw.polygon`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.ImageDraw.polygon) to outline the highlight.

```
def highlight_polygon(image, coords, *, factor=2.5, outline='tomato', width=2):
    result = image.copy()

    mask = Image.new('L', result.size)
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
    # this polygon defines the enhanced region we want to keep
    draw.polygon(coords, 'white')

    # brighten the whole image, then paste back the unmasked part
    # note this is inefficient, you only need to enhance the area
    # defined by the bounding box of the polygon
    result.paste(
        ImageEnhance.Brightness(image).enhance(factor),
        mask=mask
    )

    # draw outline
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(result)
    draw.polygon(coords, outline=outline, width=width)

    return result
```

As noted in the comment, the way it works is somewhat inefficient.  You'd be better calculating the bounding box of the coordinates and only brightening that part, rather than the whole image.

The above code could be used with your example image like this:

```
coords = [(108, 136), (200, 136), (204, 154), (107, 154)]

with Image.open("product.jpg") as im:
    out = highlight_polygon(im, coords)
```

Producing the following image:

[image: image with highlight]